# Reverse a Doubly Linked List From Tail to Head

Tags: c, pointers, reverse, doubly-linked-list

I am currently practicing pointers on my school break and below I written the method to reverse a doubly linked list, but when I hand it into an online test, it fails.

```
Node* Reverse(Node *head)
{
    int count = 0;
    struct Node *ptr = head;

    // return head if NULL
    if (head == NULL) {
        return head;
    }
    // if the list is only the head, then the reverse is just the head... so nothing changes
    if((head->next == NULL && head->prev == NULL)){
        return head;
    }

    //Come here if previous if statements fail, traverse the list until I reach tail which will become the
    // new head
    while(ptr->next != NULL){
        ptr = ptr->next;
        count++;
    }
    head = ptr; // this is the new head    
    //starting from tail all the way to head swap the "prev" and "next" of each node 
    struct Node *temp = ptr->next;

    for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){
        ptr->next = ptr->prev;
        ptr->prev = temp;
        ptr=ptr->next;
        temp= ptr->next;
        //count--;
    }

    return head;
}
```

I realize that it is probably smarter to reverse the list while I traverse it from head to tail, but I thought that was boring, so I decided to reverse it starting from the tail to head instead. I suspect there is an obvious error in my while loop or for loop, but I am unable to diagnose the error.

Comment: What error does the online test give?

Comment: `struct Node` --> `Node` or `Node *head` --> `struct Node *head`

Comment: Here is the error: Wrong Answer!
Some possible errors:
1. You returned a NULL value from the function. 
2. There is a problem with your logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error is here:

```
while(ptr->next != NULL){
    ptr = ptr->next;
    count++;
}
```

Let's say your linked list has 2 elements in it. Then that `while` loop will only iterate once, and `count` will be 1. When you get down to the `for` loop, it will also only iterate once, which means you will correctly reassign the pointers for the new head, but not the second element (previously the head).

If you initialize `count` to 1 instead of 0, it should correctly reflect the number of elements in the linked list and the `for` loop should execute correctly.

**Edit:** You will also have to restructure your `for` loop slightly to avoid a segfault at the end of the list:

```
Node* temp;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    temp = ptr->next;
    ptr->next = ptr->prev;
    ptr->prev = temp;
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a  segfault when I set count to 1;

Comment: Can you please explain to me how come my for loop seg faults when I set count to = 1?

Comment: Should it be while (ptr && ptr->next) ? Just to make sure ptr is valid before ptr->next is attempted?

Comment: Oh, nvm, it's because it will "next" three times, which is out of the bounds of a 2 linked list.

Comment: @subin, at the beginning I check if head is NULL, and if it isn't, then the next NULL then I will encounter will be after the tail. So I don't check if ptr is valid.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){//i<count --> i<=count : Because Not counting last element
    ptr->next = ptr->prev;
    ptr->prev = temp;
    ptr=ptr->next;
    temp= ptr->next;//<-- bad
    //count--;
}
```

with

```
for(int i = 0; i <= count; i++){
    ptr->next = ptr->prev;
    ptr->prev = temp;
    temp = ptr;
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

or

```
while(ptr){
    ptr->next = ptr->prev;
    ptr->prev = temp;
    temp = ptr;//next prev
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```